# Beer label alcohol

Tags: ingredients

I wondered about the alcohol in a beer and it was not on the can. Neither were ingredients or calories.  Why does beer not have to list that stuff but food does?  This is Texas.

Comment: Weird. In the UK listing the alcohol content is mandatory

Comment: In Spain it's mandatory too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a great article that explains all the details, but basically, the big brewers won't be forced into divulging all their ingredients by the government.

Read this to understand it in more detail: [Why Ingredients Don't Appear on Beer Labels.](https://www.thestreet.com/story/12753874/2/why-ingredients-dont-appear-on-beer-labels.html)

Comment: For those that go to the link.  By clicking to what you think is dismissing that adware will install the adware.  I think.  Just let it time out.